# issue is to set cron job

Tags: php, cron

I am first time trying to set cron job in my linux server.
I want to set every 5 mins my file will run.
For that I did the following:

```
1. login through cpanel
2. Click Cron Jobs under Advance option.
3. In Add New Cron Job, select every 5 minutes in Common Settings and in Command text box write down the code */5 * * * * wget http://www.forwardx.in/sri/test.php  > /dev/null 
4 Click on the Add New Cron Job button.
```

But I got error like "-":1:bad command errors in crontab file, can't install.

How to resolve this issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you select the timing from common settings, all you need to type in is the command

`wget http://www.forwardx.in/sri/test.php`.

You are typing in the timing schedule as well. Try omitting the timing part.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that wget is not set in the path, so try the fullpath instead.
This should probably be "/usr/bin/wget" instead of "wget"